# Filtering data with spatie query builder using trait

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I put logic from my `function index()` of **UserController** in trait taht i created:

```
public function index()
{
    $this->authorize('view', Auth::user());
    $users = QueryBuilder::for(User::class) 
        ->allowedIncludes('kids','roles','articles','recordings')
        ->allowedFilters('first_name', 'last_name', 'email')
        ->get();
    return UserResource::collection($users);
}
```

and this is my trait :

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Traits;

use App\Models\User;
use Spatie\QueryBuilder\QueryBuilder;

trait Filterable
{
  public function filter()
  {
    $users = QueryBuilder::for(User::class) 
            ->allowedIncludes('kids','roles','articles','recordings')
            ->allowedFilters('first_name', 'last_name', 'email')
            ->get();
            return $users;
  }
}
```

So now my function index() looks like this:

```
use Filterable;

    public function index()
    {
        $this->authorize('view', Auth::user());
        $users = $this->filter();
        return UserResource::collection($users);
```

Now when i do this in my postman
`{{url}}/api/users?filter[first_name]=anna`
it works and it returns anna from my database but when I try
`{{url}}/api/users?include=roles` 
it return every user from database but does not include roles.
Can somebody help me with this?

Answer (score 2):

This is taken straight from the github page: https://github.com/spatie/laravel-query-builder#custom-filters

#### Custom filters

```
use Spatie\QueryBuilder\Filters\Filter;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;

class FiltersUserPermission implements Filter
{
    public function __invoke(Builder $query, $value, string $property) : Builder
    {
        return $query->whereHas('permissions', function (Builder $query) use ($value) {
            $query->where('name', $value);
        });
    }
}

use Spatie\QueryBuilder\Filter;

// GET /users?filter[permission]=createPosts
$users = QueryBuilder::for(User::class)
    ->allowedFilters(Filter::custom('permission', FiltersUserPermission::class))
    ->get();
// $users will contain all users that have the `createPosts` permission
```